# UnboundLocalError: local variable 'pred' referenced before assignment

Tags: python, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I'm try to classify AD diseases. When I trying to calculate the probability of a random image from test data it's showing this error. Kindly help.

---

```
UnboundLocalError 
                        Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[18], line 38
     35     ax2.set_title('Alzheimer Probabilities', color="yellow", fontweight="bold", fontsize=16)
     37 rand_img_no = np.random.randint(1, 32)
---> 38 random_mri_prob_bringer(image_number=rand_img_no)

Cell In[18], line 7, in random_mri_prob_bringer(image_number)
      4     image = images[image_number]
      5     pred = model.predict(tf.expand_dims(image, 0))[0]
----> 7 probs = list(tf.nn.softmax(pred).numpy()) 
      8 probs_dict = dict(zip(class_dist.keys(), probs))
     10 keys = list(probs_dict.keys())

UnboundLocalError: local variable 'pred' referenced before assignment
```

---

This is a function that fetches a random image and displays a pie chart showing the probability distribution of which target value the image belongs to, represented as percentages. In this way, it will be seen which class the model gives the highest probability to

```
def random_mri_prob_bringer(image_number=0):
    
    for images, _ in test_data.skip(5).take(1):
        image = images[image_number]
        pred = model.predict(tf.expand_dims(image, 0))[0]
        
    probs = list(tf.nn.softmax(pred).numpy()) 
    probs_dict = dict(zip(class_dist.keys(), probs))
    
    keys = list(probs_dict.keys())
    values = list(probs_dict.values())

    fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(1, 2, facecolor='black')
    plt.subplots_adjust(wspace=0.4) 
    ax1.imshow(image)
    ax1.set_title('Brain MRI', color="yellow", fontweight="bold", fontsize=16)
    
    edges = ['left', 'bottom', 'right', 'top']
    edge_color = "greenyellow"
    edge_width = 3
    for edge in edges:
        ax1.spines[edge].set_linewidth(edge_width)
        ax1.spines[edge].set_edgecolor(edge_color)

    plt.gca().axes.yaxis.set_ticklabels([])        
    plt.gca().axes.xaxis.set_ticklabels([])

    wedges, labels, autopct = ax2.pie(values, labels=keys,  autopct='%1.1f%%', shadow=True, startangle=90, colors=colors, textprops={'fontsize': 8, "fontweight":"bold", "color":"white"},  wedgeprops={'edgecolor':'black'} , labeldistance=1.15)

    for autotext in autopct:
        autotext.set_color('black')

    ax2.set_title('Alzheimer Probabilities', color="yellow", fontweight="bold", fontsize=16)
    
rand_img_no = np.random.randint(1, 32)
random_mri_prob_bringer(image_number=rand_img_no)
```

Comment: It looks like the line: `pred = model.predict(...` may not execute since it is inside a `for` loop. If that happens (ie the for loop has no items to iterate over), then the next line will result in the error reported.

Comment: The loop is never run, `test_data.skip(5).take(1)` is empty.